# How do you place a specific array item using .InnerHTML method

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml

Okay, here's the issue I'm running into: I am attempting to create a basic array to contain menu items for each day of the week to display on a menuboard. I need to access only one item from the array at a time, and am attempting to use the .innerHTML method to place the item into the HTML. However, I am running into an issue where it doesn't show the text unless I have included the array items preceding the item I am attempting to access.

I have 2 .js files working in tandem with an HTML file. One is the loader for the menu items and I have a separate .js file for the array since I wanted it to be easy for anyone to update in the future without fear of them scrambling the code into oblivion.

For example: I try to choose the array item "1", but it doesn't display unless I also place array item "0" before it in the HTML. I would indicate that I want array item "1" by coding `pizza2` as the ID for dynamic item in the HTML. Essentially, I cannot select `pizza2`without first having a separate `<p>` element referencing `pizza1`prior to it.

I am relatively new to JS, so I'm not sure what to do at this point to troubleshoot. Here's my code:

The HTML:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="pizza.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye|Bitter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Forces Cache Clear-->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

</head>

<body>

<!--Body-->
<section class="pizza_menu">
    <h1>Pizza</h1>
    <h1 style="line-height: 0.05em">Station</h1>
  <div class="items">
  <p>Cheese Pizza</p>
  <p>Pepperoni Pizza</p>
<!--Dynamic Menu Item-->
  <p id="pizza2"></p>
</div>
</section>

<!--Video Background-->
<section class="background">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://corinthdesign.com/private/HTML_menuboards/media/pizza.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>

  <script src="menus/pizzaMenu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/menuLoader.js"></script>
</body>
```

The js to load the menu (including "console.log" lines to help ensure that it is able to connect the ID's with the items in the array, which it does):

````
//MONDAY
var a0 = menu[0]
//TUESDAY
var b1 = menu[1]
//WEDNESDAY
var c2 = menu[2]
//THURSDAY
var d3 = menu[3]
//FRIDAY
var e4 = menu[4]
//SATURDAY
var f5 = menu[5]
//SUNDAY
var g6 = menu[6]

$(document).ready(function menuLoader() {
  console.log(menu[0]);
  console.log(menu[1]);
  console.log(menu[2]);
  console.log(menu[3]);
  console.log(menu[4]);
  console.log(menu[5]);
  console.log(menu[6]);

/////////Below code places menu items///////////
//Monday
  document.getElementById("pizza1").innerHTML = a0;
  document.getElementById("pizza2").innerHTML = b1;
  document.getElementById("pizza3").innerHTML = c2;
  document.getElementById("pizza4").innerHTML = d3;
  document.getElementById("pizza5").innerHTML = e4;
  document.getElementById("pizza6").innerHTML = f5;
  document.getElementById("pizza7").innerHTML = g6;
});
    ```
````

Finally, the simple js array menu file:

```
var menu = [

//Monday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Meat Lover's Pizza",
//Tuesday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Grilled Vegetable Pizza",
//Wednesday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Cheeseburger Pizza",
//Thursday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Mac and Cheese Pizza",
//Friday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Tandoori Chicken Pizza",
//Saturday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Chicken Bruschetta Pizza",
//Sunday Lunch and Dinner Special
  "Sausage Pizza"

]
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Why are you creating extra variables for your array elements? e.g. `a0`

Comment: The system I'm using will require me to have a separate HTML document for each day of the week, and having each array element easily selectable as a variable simplifies it to ensure that the proper day's menu item is being placed. At least, that was the idea. I'm open to suggestions as to how to code it more efficiently.

Comment: So then, why are you even using arrays?

Comment: I was hoping to make is as easy as possible for others to edit the menu. If all they have to do it replace the text in an array, it is less likely to be done incorrectly.

Comment: Where is `pizza1` etc in your html above?

Comment: ```pizza1``` is not the array item I am hoping to access. I am trying to place ```pizza2``` into that ```<p>```. If I put ```pizza1``` it displays with no problem, however, ```pizza2``` will not, and I cannot figure out why

Comment: You only have `pizza2` (not 1, 3,4,5 etc) in your html. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I understand that I only have pizza2 in the HTML. That's on purpose. I will have a different HTML document for each day of the week, each referencing only one of the items in the Array. That way someone can update the menu in the array and it will update every day of the week in one go.

Comment: See my answer. If there's anything I've missed then let me know in that answer's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get the current day and use that to look up the appropriate menu from the list provided:

```js
var menu =
{ 
  "Monday" : "Meat Lover's Pizza",
  "Tuesday" : "Grilled Vegetable Pizza",
  "Wednesday" : "Cheeseburger Pizza",
  "Thursday" : "Mac and Cheese Pizza",
  "Friday" : "Tandoori Chicken Pizza",
  "Saturday" : "Chicken Bruschetta Pizza",
  "Sunday" : "Sausage Pizza"
};


var date = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = date.toLocaleDateString("en-gb", { weekday: 'long' });  

document.getElementById("pizzaOfTheDay").innerHTML = menu[dayOfWeek];
```

```html
<!--Body-->
<section class="pizza_menu">
    <h1>Pizza</h1>
    <h1 style="line-height: 0.05em">Station</h1>
  <div class="items">
  <p>Cheese Pizza</p>
  <p>Pepperoni Pizza</p>
<!--Dynamic Menu Item-->
  <p id="pizzaOfTheDay"></p>
</div>
</section>

<!--Video Background-->
<section class="background">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://corinthdesign.com/private/HTML_menuboards/media/pizza.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. That's a much simpler solution overall and simplifies the entire js. I appreciate it!

Comment: Tidy solution! A further simplification *could* be achieved by using `.getDate()` instead of `.toLocaleDateString("en-gb", { weekday: 'long' })` and using a plain array for the menu (which would need to start with Sunday's special), but the current one scores on readability.

Comment: @cars10m Thanks. I was trying to keep the js as simple as possible as other users of his site will be content managing the data.